# Wrong value in console.log

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

I have the following snippets in javascript whose output makes me feel that something is going wrong.

`1.`

```
a=2;
console.log(a);
a+=2;
console.log(a);
```

**Output:`2  4`** ; as expected

`2.`

```
t=[0,2];
console.log(t);
t[0]+=2;
console.log(t);
```

***Output: [2,2] [2,2]***

**Shouldn't the output be** ***`[0,2] [2,2]`*** ***?***  **And whats the difference between the above two cases that results in the different answers in both the cases?**

Comment: I got your expected output in the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: I got the expected output in firefox.

Comment: yep, in latest version of chrome

Comment: is this a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays

Comment: Me too in latest Chrome. Getting expected value. Guess they improved their performance since 2012.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's because the log is delayed until Chrome has time to do it (i.e. your scripts releases the CPU).

Try this to understand what happens :

```
var t=[0,2];
console.log(t);
setTimeout(function() {
     t[0]+=2;
   console.log(t);
}, 1000);
```

It outputs what you expect.

Is that a bug of Chrome ? Maybe a side effect of an optimization. At least it's a dangerous design...

Why is there a difference ? I suppose Chrome stores temporarily what it must log, as a primary (immutable) value in the first case, as a pointer to the array in the last case.

Comment: yeah, veryyy often they are playing with fire

Comment: yep, chrome seems to be doing lots of changes these days.. thanks btw :)

Answer (score 8):

console.log in chrome/ff is asynchronous and objects that are logged are interpreted at the time when they're expanded. . Instead make a copy of the object if you want to see its value at that time (for an array):

```
t=[0,2];
console.log(t.slice(0));
t[0]+=2;
console.log(t);
```

With an array, calling .slice will duplicate the array and not create a reference.
I wouldn't suggest using a time out: this really doesn't *solve* the problem, just circumvents it temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you're doing is right, but chrome's logging is screwy/delayed. Try making a copy of the variable and adding to that and you'll see that your code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's logging is delayed in the newer versions, no problem from your end. Make a copy of the variable or use `setTimeout`.