# I can console.log my array but it's values shows up as undefined when appended to a div

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I can console.log the array before and after I step through it to build list items. When I run the code I get 10 list items in my html that all read "undefined" instead of being the values I'm pulling out of my chrome history.

Any ideas as to why?

```
var urlarray = []

var historyResults = function () {

var microsecondsPerWeek = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
var oneWeekAgo = (new Date).getTime() - microsecondsPerWeek;

chrome.history.search({
    'text': '',            // Return every history item....
    'startTime': oneWeekAgo  // that was accessed less than one week ago.
}, function(historyItems) {
    for (var i = 0; i < historyItems.length; ++i) {
        urlarray.push(historyItems[i].url);
}
})
console.log(urlarray)

}

historyResults()


function addElement () { 

var makeUL = function(data) {

var ul = document.createElement("ul");
// create the UL 

console.log(urlarray)

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = data[i];
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i]));
    console.log(a)
var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(a);
ul.appendChild(li);
// step through the array and create a link out of the value of the array and append them to the list item
// append the list item to the UL
}

return ul;
// return ul full of li
}

console.log(urlarray)
document.getElementById("arraylist").appendChild(makeUL(urlarray));
// go to html to find div and append the full UL with urlarray as the array
}

addElement()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Chrome’s JavaScript console lazy about evaluating objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chrome-s-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues going on.

First, you are logging the array, but your browser does not log it *immediately*.  It does so when it has the CPU available.  When you log the array, its not yet populated with values.  A moment later, when you expand the array in your browser console, the array is now populated *because the evaluation of the array is delayed*.

You can see this more clearly if you change your logging statement to: `console.log(JSON.stringify(urlarray))`.  This forces the immediate evaluation of the object and turns it into a JSON string, which can then be written to the browser console a moment later.

**For more information on the delayed evaluation of logged objects, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214430/wrong-value-in-console-log).**

Okay, this brings us to your second issue.  Your logging statement is executing before the callback to `chrome.history.search` does.  That's why the array isn't yet populated.  You need to use promises to ensure your code executes in the expected sequence.  For this you should use a library like jQuery or Q.

I recommend reading about promises.  Whichever library you use, your code will follow this basic structure:

1. Get a 'deferred' object.  I'll call it `deferred`.
2. In your callback, resolve `deferred` with the array: `deferred.resolve(urlarray)`
3. Where your logging statement is, get the promise from the deferred object.  Return that promise from the `historyResults` method.
4. Where you call `historyResults`, instead do:

```
historyResults.then(function(urls) { 
    console.log("promise was resolved!", urls);
    // do things with your urls here, like add elements
});
```

Do things that depend on your urls *here*, inside this callback.  If you do, your code will be guaranteed to execute when the urls array is fully populated and ready to go.

This is a big topic, so google "javascript promises" and good luck.  I hope this helps to get you started in the right direction.

**If you don't want to use promises:**

If you don't want to use promises, you will need to do everything inside the callback to `chrome.history.search`.  That's the only way to guarantee the array is populated.

Asynchronous code is fun.