# Why does jQuery each() function behave like it's asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I saw like many people answered that jQuery each() function isn't asynchronous. But I don't understand why this function behaves a certain way. Could anybody explain why this code:

```
var otherArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var array = [];
console.log(array);

$(otherArray).each(function () {
    array[1] = $(this);
});
```

has this output:

[image]

But that code:

```
var otherArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var array = [];
console.log(array);

$(otherArray).each(function () {
    // array[1] = $(this);
})
```

has that output:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214430/wrong-value-in-console-log

Comment: You overwrite the same array element each iteration by hard coding the index `1`. Try using the index parameter of the `each` callback instead

Comment: @charlietfl it doesn't matter. Problem is that console.log() displays incorrect value.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks, Jeff. It solves my issue. It appears that in Chrome there is just a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The console you see in Chrome/Firefox doesn't actually provide an exact snapshot of what an object *was* at the time of `console.log`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays).

The code is indeed running synchronously. To verify this, print a "primitive" value, e.g. the length of the array:

```
var otherArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var array = [];
console.log(array.length);

$(otherArray).each(function () {
  array[1] = $(this);
});
```

Should print `0` as expected.

Comment: Yes, it prints length correctly. But when you need to have array itself printed, the better way to use `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array)));`